# Youtube didChangeToState is not fired when (re-)buffering on iOS8

Tags: ios, iframe, youtube-api

I would like to detect when rebuffering (i.e. when buffering takes place when a video has started playing) occurs when playing a YouTube video using YouTube's library (build on top of iFrame) for iOS. I have followed the instructions (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) on how to configure and start a video. Everything works as expected on iPhones running iOS 9 but when running the same code on an iPhone with iOS 8 the method didChangeToState with the state YTPlayerState.Buffering is never called (after the YTPlayerState.Playing is called) even though it is obvious that the video sometimes is rebuffering.

There is an issue reported about approximately the same behaviour with the difference that the iFrame library is used directly in an UIWebView: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6680 
My guess is that my problem is related with this one.

**Is there any way of detecting rebuffering on iOS 8 using YouTube's library for iOS?**

I use the following code to detect rebuffering:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: YTPlayerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("View did load")
        playerView.delegate = self

        let playerVars: [NSObject: AnyObject] = ["playsinline":1] // Plays the video in the UIView instead of fullscreen. To programmatically control playback.
        playerView.loadWithVideoId("M7lc1UVf-VE", playerVars: playerVars)
    }
}

extension ViewController: YTPlayerViewDelegate {

    // MARK: YTPlayerViewDelegate

    func playerView(playerView: YTPlayerView!, didChangeToState state: YTPlayerState) {
        switch state {
        case .Buffering:
            print("Buffering")
            break
        case .Ended:
            print("Ended")
            break
        case .Paused:
            print("Paused")
            break
        case .Playing:
            print("Playing")
            break
        case .Queued:
            print("Queued")
            break
        case .Unknown:
            print("Unknown")
            break
        case .Unstarted:
            print("Unstarted")
            break
        }
    }

    func playerView(playerView: YTPlayerView!, receivedError error: YTPlayerError) {
        print("Error: " + "\(error)")
    }

    func playerViewDidBecomeReady(playerView: YTPlayerView!) {
        print("Player did become ready")
        self.playerView!.playVideo()
    }
}
```

On a network with low bandwidth I get the following output from an iPhone with iOS 9 (rebuffering in italic): 
View did load 
Player did become ready 
Buffering 
Playing 
*Buffering* 
Playing 
. 
. 
. 
*Buffering* 
Playing 
Ended

On iOS 8, on the other hand, the output is only (independent of the bandwidth): 
View did load 
Player did become ready 
Buffering 
Playing 
Ended

Comment: You should open an Issue on the official GitHub repo of the YTPlayerView here: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

Comment: Thanks @JAL! An issued is filed as you suggested: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/175